# Change color of android bar

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have created an app with Nativescript Angular, but if I have all running apps displayed in Android, the bar is always white. Does anyone know how I can customize it? For example like the one from Gmail or the Playstore. It would be best if I could adjust it dynamically in the app itself fitting to the theme chosen by the user, or it always takes over the color of the action bar.

[image]

**Edit:**

I found out how to hardcode the color -> change ns_primary in the *colors.xml* file

But I didn't manage to get the color of my ActionBar adopted. I think the color of the ActionBar will be overwritten by an xml file of mine, but I couldn't figure out how to prevent it. Do you know what I have to change in my files to achieve this?

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="__PACKAGE__"
      android:versionCode="10001"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
</application>
```

*styles.xml*

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- theme to use FOR launch screen-->
<style name="LaunchScreenThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>

    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>

<style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase">
</style>

<!-- theme to use AFTER launch screen is loaded-->
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
</style>

<!-- theme for action-bar -->
<style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/ns_primary</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat</item>
</style>

<style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyle" parent="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase">
</style>
```

*colors.xml*

```
<resources>
    <color name="ns_primary">#F5F5F5</color>
    <color name="ns_primaryDark">#757575</color>
    <color name="ns_accent">#33B5E5</color>
    <color name="ns_blue">#272734</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the theme in `styles.xml` inside App_resources->values

```
<style name="LaunchScreenThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

</style>
<style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase"></style>
<!-- theme to use AFTER launch screen is loaded-->
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
</style>
```

and you can define these colors in App_resources->values->colors.xml

```
<resources>
<color name="ns_primary">#c66900</color>
<color name="ns_primaryDark">#c66900</color>
<color name="ns_mainbg">#E5E5E8</color>
<color name="ns_accent">#33B5E5</color>
<color name="ns_blue">#2196F3</color>
<color name="ns_transparent">#00000000</color>
<color name="ns_white">#FFFFFF</color>


<color name="ns_color_accent_custom">#4CAF50</color>
<color name="ns_color_primary_custom">#CDDC39</color>
<color name="ns_color_primary_secondary">#AFB42B</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `backgroundColor` and `color` attributes on `ActionBar`.

```
<ActionBar title="ActionBar Style" color="white" backgroundColor="red">  
</ActionBar>
```

Or you could simply add this in your `app.css` to apply it throughout app

```
ActionBar {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

You may also be interested in https://www.nativescriptthemebuilder.com/ and [nativescript-themes](https://github.com/nathanaela/nativescript-themes) plugin, together it helps you change your theme dynamically at runtime which should help you provide the theme user picks up.

While you may still able to change the colors by modifying `styles.xml` / `colors.xml` from `App_resources/Android/src/main/res`. But this will be specific to Android and static over all the pages in app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change dynamically then you can use:

window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color. colorPrimary)